# MySQL query is slow only when using ORDER BY field DESC and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

### Overview

I'm running MySQL 5.7.30-33, and I'm hitting an issue that seems like MySQL is using the wrong index when running a query. I'm getting a 3 second query time using my existing query. However, just by changing the ORDER BY, removing the LIMIT, or forcing a USE INDEX I can get a 0.01 second query time. Unfortunately I need to stick with my original query (it's baked into an application), so it'd be great if this disparity could be resolved in the schema/indexing.

### Setup / problem

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `referrals` (
  `__id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `systemcreated` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `referrerid` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `referrersiteid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ... lots more mediumtext fields ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`__id`),
  KEY `systemcreated` (`systemcreated`,`referrersiteid`,`__id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53368 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

The table only has ~55k rows, but is very wide, as some of the fields contain huge BLOBs:

```
mysql> show table status like 'referrals'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: referrals
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compressed
           Rows: 45641
 Avg_row_length: 767640
    Data_length: 35035897856
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 3653632
      Data_free: 3670016
 Auto_increment: 54008
    Create_time: 2020-12-12 12:46:14
    Update_time: 2020-12-12 17:50:28
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: row_format=COMPRESSED
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My customer's application queries the table using this, and unfortunately that can't easily be changed:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  referrals
    WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
      AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
    order by  __id desc
    limit  16;
```

This results in a query time around 3 seconds.

The EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referrals   | NULL       | index | systemcreated | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   32 |     5.56 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Note that it is using the PRIMARY key for the query rather than the `systemcreated` index.

### Experimentation 1

If I change the query to use ASC rather than DESC:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  referrals
    WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
      AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
    order by  __id asc
    limit  16;
```

then it takes 0.01 seconds, and the EXPLAIN looks to be the same:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referrals   | NULL       | index | systemcreated | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   32 |     5.56 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

### Experimentation 2

If I change the query to stick with ORDER BY __id DESC, but remove the LIMIT:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  referrals
    WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
      AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
    order by  __id desc;
```

then it also takes 0.01 seconds, with an EXPLAIN like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referrals   | NULL       | range | systemcreated | systemcreated | 406     | NULL | 2086 |    11.11 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

### Experimentation 3

Alternatively, if I force the original query to use the `systemcreated` index then it also gives a 0.01 sec query time. Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
mysql> explain     SELECT  *
    FROM  referrals USE INDEX (systemcreated)
    WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
      AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
    order by  __id desc
    limit  16;

+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referrals    | NULL       | range | systemcreated | systemcreated | 406     | NULL | 2086 |    11.11 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

### Experimentation 4

Lastly, if I use the original ORDER BY __id DESC LIMIT 16 but select fewer fields, then it also returns in 0.01 seconds! Here's the explain:

```
mysql> explain     SELECT  field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
    FROM  referrals
    WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
      AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
    order by  __id desc
    limit  16;

+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | referrals   | NULL       | index | systemcreated | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   32 |     5.56 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

### Summary

So the only combination that seems to be performing poorly is `ORDER BY __id DESC LIMIT 16`.

I *think* I have the indexes setup correctly. I'm querying via the `systemcreated` and `referrersiteid` fields, and ordering by __id, so I have an index defined as (systemcreated, referrersiteid, __id), but MySQL still seems to be using the PRIMARY key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe running `ANALYZE TABLE referrals` allows the DBMS to make a better decision?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: ANALYZE TABLE made no difference. There's 16GB in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Avg_row_length: 767640"; lots of `MEDIUMTEXT`.  A row is limited to about 8KB; overflow goes into "off-record" blocks.  Reading those blocks takes extra disk hits.
- `SELECT *` will reach for all those fat columns.  The total will be about 50 reads (of 16KB each).  This takes time.
- (Exp 4) `SELECT a,b,c,d` ran faster because it did not need to fetch all ~50 blocks per row.
- Your secondary index, (`systemcreated`,`referrersiteid`,`__id`), -- only the first column is useful.  This is because of `systemcreated LIKE 'xxx%'`.  This is a "range".  Once a range is hit, the rest of the index is ineffective.  Except...
- "Index hints" (`USE INDEX(...)`) may help today but may make things worse tomorrow when the data distribution changes.
- If you can't get rid of the wild cards in `LIKE`, I recommend these two indexes:

  ```
    INDEX(systemcreated)
    INDEX(referrersiteid)
  ```
- The real speedup can occur by turning the query inside out.  That is, find the 16 ids first, then go looking for all those bulky columns:

  ```
    SELECT  r2...   -- whatever you want
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT  __id
                FROM  referrals
                WHERE  `systemcreated` LIKE 'XXXXXX%'
                  AND  `referrersiteid` LIKE 'XXXXXXXXXXXX%'
                order by  __id desc
                limit  16 
        ) AS r1
        JOIN  referrals r2 USING(__id)
        ORDER BY  __id DESC   -- yes, this needs repeating
  ```

And keep the 3-column secondary index that you have.  Even if it must scan a lot more than 16 rows to find the 16 desired, it is a lot less bulky.  This means that the subquery ("derived table") will be moderately fast.  Then the outer query will still have 16 lookups -- possibly 16*50 blocks to read.  The total number of blocks read will still be a lot less.

There is rarely a noticeable difference between `ASC` and `DESC` on `ORDER BY`.

Why does the Optimizer pick the PK instead of the seemingly better secondary index?  The PK *might* be best, especially if the 16 rows are at the 'end' (DESC) of the table.  But that would be a terrible choice if it had to scan the entire table without finding 16 rows.

Meanwhile, the wildcard test makes the secondary index only partially useful.  The Optimizer makes a decision based on inadequate statistics.  Sometimes it feels like the flip of a coin.

If you use my inside-out reformulation, then I recommend the follow two composite indexes -- The Optimizer can make a semi-intelligent, semi-correct choice between them for the derived table:

```
INDEX(systemcreated, referrersiteid, __id),
INDEX(referrersiteid, systemcreated, __id)
```

It will continue to say "filesort", but don't worry; it's only sorting 16 rows.

And, remember, `SELECT *` is hurting performance.  (Though maybe you can't fix that.)

Comment: Thanks very much! Your suggestion of adding separate indexes on `systemcreated` and `referrersiteid` did the trick. In fact, `INDEX(referrersiteid)` alone did the job. I suspect my issue may have had something to do with the cardinality of the data - systemcreated only has a few unique values, whilst referrersiteid has tens of thousands.

Comment: @SamCrawford - Since you are using a range test, the cardinality is not the metric -- rather the number of rows that satisfy `LIKE '...%'`.  Keep both indexes; the Optimizer will dynamically figure out which is better for each query.

Comment: Understood, thanks. And having re-read your original answer, I now realise that if I had the original secondary index as (referrersiteid, systemcreated, __id) then all would have been fine. I didn't know that an index stopped being used after the first successful range match. So thanks again for improving my knowledge!

Comment: @SamCrawford - I have more tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql